# How can I change the state of a button if a user has clicked a checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have an unusual need. I have five input checkboxes that look like this:

```
<input class="abc" id="Response[0]" name="Response[0]" type="checkbox" />
<input class="abc" id="Response[1]" name="Response[1]" type="checkbox" />
<input class="abc" id="Response[2]" name="Response[2]" type="checkbox" />
<input class="abc" id="Response[3]" name="Response[3]" type="checkbox" />
```

I have a button that the user can click but I want that disabled until the user has clicked in one of the check boxes.

Is there some way that I can sense the user having clicked in a checkbox and then change the state of the button from disabled="disabled" if this has happened. I already use jQuery on the page so I am hoping for a simple jQuery solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this isn't hard to do with [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change). I'm going to assume that you don't mind if more than one of the checkboxes is checked, as long as at least one is...

```
$('input.abc').change(function() {
    if ($('input.abc:checked').length) {
        $('#yourButton').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#yourButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

<s>Note that it would be a significant improvement if you could give the input elements a [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector), or if you could specify a [common parent element](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector) that had no other `input` children. The [attribute-starts-with selector `name^="value"`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with) is fairly slow.</s>

Edit: changed to a class selector.

Comment: Nice one, was going to suggest something very similar: http://jsfiddle.net/GWsFU/ :)

Comment: I gave the attributes a class. I didn't know the above would be slow. If you don't mind could you modify your solution to make it clear for me and others how to implement if there was a class. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dave, then change the selector `'input[name^="Response["]'` to `'input.yourclass'`.

Comment: @Dave Changed to a class selector.

Comment: @lonesomeday - I am sorry. Can I ask if it would be even easier if I used just the one class for a DIV that contains the buttons? I changed my question again so you could see that. I don't know much about jQuery selectors so I am not really sure how to change the selector with the code modified for the second time

Comment: @lovesomeday - I will mark your answer as accepted as I really like your solution. However I also like Darin's solution. I wish I could accept both.

Comment: @Dave What you've actually done is delete all the code from your question... A parent element *and* a class would be best, which would look something like `$('#parentElementId input.abc')`

Comment: @lonesomeday - Code was deleted for a minute by accident. I think that was the minute you clicked on refresh. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

There are [several ways to check if a checkbox is checked](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html).  Here's one:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
    // Do stuff with button.
  }
});
```

Comment: There are several ways, and that's a poor one. `$(this).prop('checked')` would be a big improvement; best of all would be `this.checked`.

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe for the click event of all those checkboxes and once the user clicks on one of them enable the button:

```
$(':checkbox[id^="Response"]').click(function() {
    $('#id_of_button').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Hello Darin, Should I use the .click or .change?  I see another person was suggesting .change so I am wondering what the difference is.

Comment: @Dave Heart, for checkboxes it's the same. But for radio buttons not exactly: click would be triggered everytime the user clicks on the radio, whereas change only if he clicks on another radio and the current one changes its value.